# Training data preparation for Training ELMO Embedding from scratch

Tags: python, tensorflow, elmo

I am trying to build my own custom chemical domain ELMO embedding. I am following the instruction from https://github.com/allenai/bilm-tf

How do I prepare the training data if I have many multi word token in domain like chemistry. For example:

**1. Original Sentences:** "This is a multi word chemical component 3-(4,5-dimethylthiazol-2-yl)-2,5-diphenyl tetrazolium bromide. \n This is another sentence."

Here "3-(4,5-dimethylthiazol-2-yl)-2,5-diphenyl tetrazolium bromide" is a single token. There are multiple words inside the token which are white space separated. This would lead to the above token to be split as 3 tokens: ['3-(4,5-dimethylthiazol-2-yl)-2,5-diphenyl','tetrazolium', 'bromide'].

How can I avoid this? Can I give the input training data in the following format to avoid this?

**Training data(1)** : List of tokens for each sentences. So the training text file will have list of list tokens.

[['This', 'is', 'a', 'multi', 'word', 'chemical', 'component', '3-(4,5-dimethylthiazol-2-yl)-2,5-diphenyl tetrazolium bromide'], ['This', 'is', 'another', 'sentence.']]

**Training data(2)**: Here I have concatenated the multi keyword token by '|' symbol.
"This is a multi word chemical component 3-(4,5-dimethylthiazol-2-yl)-2,5-diphenyl|tetrazolium|bromide. \n This is another sentence."

Please guide on the best way to prepare the training data.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom spaCy Tokenizer by adding your own special case.

First, install the packages needed.

```
pip install spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

Then, run the following code.

```
import spacy
from spacy.symbols import ORTH

input = "This is a multi word chemical component 3-(4,5-dimethylthiazol-2-yl)-2,5-diphenyl tetrazolium bromide.\nThis is another sentence."
output = []

nlp_tokenisation = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm") # Initialise

# Add additional rules
special_case = [{ORTH: "3-(4,5-dimethylthiazol-2-yl)-2,5-diphenyl tetrazolium bromide"}]
nlp_tokenisation.tokenizer.add_special_case("3-(4,5-dimethylthiazol-2-yl)-2,5-diphenyl tetrazolium bromide", special_case)

input = input.split("\n") # Split lines

for line in input:
    doc = nlp_tokenisation(line)
    output.append([token.text for token in doc])

print(output)
```

It should return you the following output:

```
[['This', 'is', 'a', 'multi', 'word', 'chemical', 'component', '3-(4,5-dimethylthiazol-2-yl)-2,5-diphenyl tetrazolium bromide', '.'], ['This', 'is', 'another', 'sentence', '.']]
```

You can then tweak the tokenizer to your desire (e.g. finetuning punctuations). You can create a script to input all chemistry terms into this tokenizer automatically.
For more information on spaCy refer to their documentation on [Tokenizer](https://spacy.io/api/tokenizer) and [Linguistic Features](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#special-cases). Although this response is late, hope it helps future developers.